# Flask. Не удается получить параметры запроса

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

На сервере крутится html файл с js. В js каждую секунду вызывается метод обновления данных.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
function setPost() {
    var send = [
    "c0_0_0_mon_boolFlow",
    ];
    xhr.open("POST", '/api/get-data', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
    xhr.onreadystatechange = onResponse;
    xhr.send(send);
}
```

На сервере этот запрос обрабатывается следующим образом:

```
from flask import Flask, request

@app.route("/api/get-data", methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    from get_data import calc
    # calc() # пробежаться по файлам, указанным в запросе и вернуть их содержимое
    print(request.args)
    return 'test'
```

Параметры в send отправляю, но request.args всегда возвращает ImmutableMultiDict([]). Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Comment: А нужно получить `json` `["c0_0_0_mon_boolFlow",]`?

Comment: @gil9red я всегда думал, что там будет строка, ибо когда я не использовал flask, а напрямую из JS вызывал скрипт get_data, то в get_data я разбирал данные следующим образом:
`data = sys.stdin.read()
listData = data.split(',')`
(завтра обязательно проверю ваш ответ (просто уже все выключил))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, `request.args` возвращает аргументы в `url` в виде словаря, например для `/api/get-data?abc=123`, вернуло бы `{acb=123}`. Поэтому, у вас всегда пустой словарь возвращался.

А для того чтобы получить тело POST-запроса как `JSON`, используйте `request.get_json()`:

```
@app.route("/api/get-data", methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
    return 'test'
```

---

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

@app.route("/api/get-data", methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    data = request.get_json()
    print('args:', request.args)
    print('data:', data)
    return 'test'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=5000)
```

Скрипт для тестирования:

```
import requests
rs = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/get-data', json=["c0_0_0_mon_boolFlow"])
print(rs)

rs = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/get-data?value=123', json=["c0_0_0_mon_boolFlow"])
print(rs)
```

Консоль сервера:

```
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/Nov/2018 11:43:50] "POST /api/get-data HTTP/1.1" 200 -
args: ImmutableMultiDict([])
data: ['c0_0_0_mon_boolFlow']
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/Nov/2018 11:43:50] "POST /api/get-data?value=123 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
args: ImmutableMultiDict([('value', '123')])
data: ['c0_0_0_mon_boolFlow']
```

Comment: почему-то ничего не возвращает. и если это написать, то выдает ошибку POST /api/get-data HTTP/1.1 400

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас тот порт кто-то слушает и у него нет пути "/api/get-data", поэтому вы и не видите. Попробуйте указать другой порт в `app.run(...` и попробовать снова

Comment: нет, не помогло.

Comment: Точно... с 404 перепутал. У вас flask как `app.debug = True` запущен? Было бы полезно узнать ошибку

Comment: Он никаких ошибок и не выдает. Просто если вызывать request.get_json(), в консоли, где сервер запускал вылетает ошибка 400 и страничка просто не обновляется. Если убрать вызов, то статус 200. debug включен

Comment: Обновил ответ, `json=` отправляет данные как `application/json`, так что оно должно совпадать с тем, что отправил бы браузер через ajax

Comment: так и не заработало с get_json, всегда ошибка 400, а вот в get_data увидел нужную мне строку b'c0_0_0_mon_boolFlow'

Comment: @ioprst, а вы ведь посылали список `['c0_0_0_mon_boolFlow']`? Кст, попробуйте так: `request.get_json(force=True)`. А мой пример у вас заработал?

Comment: статус всегда 200 ваш пример возвращал, а лог мне почему-то не вывел) К сожалению даже так с get_json не работает. Выкрутился через request.get_data().decode('utf-8)

Comment: @ioprst, а тот лог *сервера*, статус 200 выводил скрипт, которые запросы на сервер посылал